# Check value exists before pushing into a key-value array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a KendoUI grid with a checkbox column. I am getting checked row values into an array.

```
var list = new Array();
$("#values").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("input").each(function(idx, item) {
  if (item.checked) {
    list.push({
      "Key": gridData[idx].id,
      "Value": gridData[idx].value
    });
  }
});
```

Before `toApproveTransactions.push`, I want to check if the value exists in `list`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array.find` function to do this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
if (item.checked) {
    function valueExist = (element){
        return element.value == gridData[idx].value
    }


    if (!list.find(valueExist) ){
        list.push({
          "Key": gridData[idx].id,
          "Value": gridData[idx].value
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'find', i got.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if `value` exists in `list` you can do this:

```
list.map(obj => obj.Value).indexOf(value) >= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider making key as the index of the associative array like in the following code and check whether that key exists in the array. If it does just output duplicate. This might answer your question

```js
key = 'Key';
value = 'Value';
mArray = [];

if(typeof(mArray[key])!=undefined)
  mArray[key] = value;
else
  console.log('duplicate');
```